# Structured plagiarism by using similar citations in a paragraph

Tags: research-process, citations, plagiarism

I cited a paragraph of an article, which classified some model according to different categories. For each class it contains related work from the literature. Is it plagiarism that some citations match with mine?

Structure of the cited paragraph:

- Class 1 / related work
- Class 2 / related work
- Class 3 / related work

To summarize:
I cited that the structure is obtained from the article. I did not cite, that some of the related work for each class was contained in this article.
For example I cited some paper belonging to the first class, which was the first in this category.
Is this considered as plagiarism?

Comment: Your question is not clear. 
Why do you need to pedantically repeat the classification presented in the article you refer to?

Comment: I do not want to repeat it. For each class there are several related paper. If I have similar citation as the author, how should I cite this?

Comment: Are you asking if it is plagiarism to cite the same work that someone else cites?

Comment: yes you can say that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is someone else work, cite it or it is plagiarism.

If it is your work, let it be your work.

A lazy way would be see article xyz and reference therein.
From what you describe it seems to me that you need to cite every work for each class, but maybe you can simply cite that the classifciation of the models have been presented by xyz, and you are referring to model of class *n* only.

Comment: I cited that the classification has been presented in this article. I refer to all n classes, but I do not know how I should cite the related work inside a specific class if I also want to include it?

Comment: For example: In class i he presented 10 papers. I want tom include 2 of them. Do I have to cite this in some way, since I would use the same citations?

Comment: " In class i he presented 10 papers. I want tom include 2 of them. " Then cite the work from the original author, plus the 2 papers you want to include and you are good to go.
Important thing is always to give credit. Origianl author made the effort to find and cite the 2 papers you want to cite? then cite the original author citing the 2 out of 10 papers. It is not plagiarism.

Comment: Do you imply that I cite the general classification from the author and cite the referenced paper from the respective authors? Or do I cite the referenced paper and simultaneously the work from the orignal author.

Comment: Something like this. Assume [1]  is orignal author,  [2] is referenced paper.     First possibility: Text conerning classification [1]. Text about referenced paper  [2]

Comment: Second possibility: Text conerning classification [1]. Text about referenced paper [1,2]

Comment: The first possibility, but please remember that plagiarism is taking the concepts/ideas/woks without citing, it is not the only issue. If you copy the text from almost word by word, even by referencing it, you are not doing plagiarism but you are still copying. There is a fine line between referencing and copying. Referencing is mentioing something you master or at least something you have understood, copying is ... well, copying.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped  lot.

Answer (score 3):

Note that plagiarism is about misattribution of the *ideas* of others, usually to oneself. It isn't about words or structure, necessarily.

Nothing in the question seems to imply misattribution of any idea.

In particular, with regard to citations, if you are writing some paper that extends another then citing some of the same work as the first seems perfectly natural. Likewise for a review article. In fact, it might be plagiarism *not* to cite.